# Should you use Records as a kind of object?

Tags: immutable.js

I like the idea of Records mainly because we can get away from using someObject.get('someKey')

But Record seems to operate more like some kind of template for records.

If you just instantiate Record each time you need a read only immutable object, simply because you like to access properties as someObject.key, would this be a bad idea?

Answer (score 0):

A call to Record returns a traditional JS type (class) when you call it. Ideally you should store this type reference and create new record instances from it. Otherwise stuff like inheritance-check doesn't work as intended.

You should prefer Record over traditional JS objects or Immutable Maps because of the integrity and immutability it offers while retaining the first class member access. However don't create a Record from a Map just for the sake of syntax convenience, you should use Record in place of the said Map everywhere.

Said that, bear in mind that Record has its own baggage of issues. You can read about it in my other post here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36357288/2790937