# How best to send Immutable.JS list into a stateless React component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm using Redux, Immutable.JS, and React. I want to pass an Immutable.JS list into my stateless React component. This component maps through the list and renders a child per item in the list.

Example:

```
function Cats(props) {

  function Cat(p) {
    return <li key={p.id}>p.name</li>;
  }

  return <ul>{props.cats.map(Cat)</ul>;
}
```

The `{p.id}` part breaks, because `props.cats` is an Immutable.JS list of maps, so I'd have to update my React component to say `{p.get('id')}` instead.

I'd be okay to do this, but are there better ways for a stateless React component to consume a list without having to know that it's an Immutable.JS list? This usage violates the best practice in the Redux + Immutable.JS + React best practice, "Use Immutable.JS everywhere except your dumb components". [1](https://redux.js.org/recipes/usingimmutablejs#use-immutable-js-everywhere-except-your-dumb-components)

I'm certain other people have dealt with this problem and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

You are not wrong.
If using ImmutableJs what you should do is `p.get('id')` the other way would be something like `props.cats.map(elem => <Cat id={elem.get('id')} key={elem.get('id')}/>)`
or IMHOP less elegant `props.cats.map(elem=>elem.toJs()).map(Cat)` but its just different ways of doing the same thing.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Can relate with your pain, I have documented this here - [What are disadvantages to using immutable state in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29622710/what-are-disadvantages-to-using-immutable-state-in-react/36357288#36357288).

#### For Redux

You can use `mapStateToProps` to convert immutables into normal JS (`state.toJSON()`). So the dumb (don't like that term) components should be abstracted from the actual structure of your state.

#### Otherwise

This is an issue anywhere you want abstraction between your state library and your views. One way I have been able to isolate this to some extent is to use (lenses)[https://medium.com/@drboolean/lenses-with-immutable-js-9bda85674780]. If they seem too complicated, you can make a `get([key path], source)` method and send that in props to your components and use it to fetch the value. This at least provides some abstraction.